# How to count down expired date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a voucher system with expiration. `expired` is an integer that counts down from the date it was made to the expired date. For example, I put five days to `expired` column as a validity period of this voucher.

- On October 1 = 5 days left (the day the voucher is created)
- On October 2 = 4 days left
- On October 3 = 3 days left
- On October 4 = 2 days left
- On October 5 = Last day
- On October 6 = Voucher expires

When the day changes, I want the number `expires` [sic] to be reduced by one point.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Voucher < ApplicationRecord
  # A method which will return days left count for expired date
  def expiry_day_left
    unless is_expired?
      day_count = (Time.now.to_date - created_at.to_date).numerator
      days_left = (expired - day_count)
      return "#{days_left} left"
     else
       return "Voucher expired"
     end
  end

  # A method which will return true or false if voucher has expired or not
  def is_expired?
    day_count = (Time.now.to_date - created_at.to_date).numerator
    return day_count > expired ? true : false
  end
end
```

Comment: your first code shows how long the voucher has been created

Comment: @Garbela I have just updated answer, it will return how many days left for expire. and 2nd method will return whether its expired or not. let's try it and let me know for any further guidance.

Comment: Worked Great. Thanyou very much sir

Comment: @Garbela Great to know that, I have given you just as example you can modify it accordingly, also feel free to upvote/ accept answer for future SO searchers.